# Install IPython on stand-alone windows machine

Tags: ipython

How can I install IPython on a Windows machine not connected to Internet.

I only need the shell without the notebooks.

I couldn't find dependency list - all installation instructions use pip and recommend avoiding manual install.

Answer (score 0):

From the [ipython.org webpage](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/install/install.html#installing-ipython-itself) there is a quickstart guide which says:

> Given a properly built Python, the basic interactive IPython shell will work with no external dependencies.

However, it is also stated that

> IPython is organized into a number of subpackages, each of which has its own dependencies. All of the subpackages come with IPython, so you don’t need to download and install them separately. However, to use a given subpackage, you will need to install all of its dependencies.

Hence, which additional packages to install mainly depends on what subpackages are going to be used. It is then possible to check the dependencies for those separately.

On Windows and OS X some features will be missing without the [readline](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyreadline) module. So it's recommended to install it.

> The IPython shell will work without readline, but will lack many features that users depend on, such as tab completion and command line editing.